# How to get the angle of a specific portion of a circle?

Tags: trigonometry

## Introduction

I have this problem. **I want to know the amount of damage something is exposed from an explosion**. Everything is bidimensional. There are two obvious conclusions considering the properties of a circle:

- The further from an explosion something is, the less percentage of it it will take, and vice-versa.
- The wider an object is, the more percentage of it it will take, and vice-versa.

## What did I try?

To try to figure this out I drew a line from the center of the explosion to the two corners of my object (the corners that are towards the center of the explosion). This created a triangle. In my opinion, if I divide the angle of that triangle over the total sum of the angles of the circle, that would give me the percentage of the explosion something is being exposed.

To make it easier, I divided this triangle into two parts so that I had a 45º angle at the base so that I could use some trigonometry. I know the distance (adjacent) and the width of the object (opposite) so to get the angle I want I need to use the identity $tan(x) = \frac{opposite}{ adjacent}$. Obviously, as I divided the triangle into two parts, I also divided the width (opposite) into two parts. To get x, I used the inverse of tangent, the cotangent (arctan). Afterward, I multiplied it again by 2 (as I previously divided the width by 2 to apply trigonometry easily).

Finally, to get it in a percentage form, I divided this by the total number of radiants in a circle, which is $2 * \pi$. Alternatively, I could make it from radiants to degrees by multiplying this by $\frac{180}{\pi}$ and then dividing it by 360º.

Therefore, the formula is $ArcTan(\frac{w / 2}{d}) * \frac{2}{(2 * \pi)}$ where:

- ArcTan is the inverse of tangent trigonometric formula.
- w is the width of the object that will take the damage.
- d is the distance of the object from the center of the explosion.

[image]

The only thing that is a bit weird is that if the explosion is made at a distance of 0.0001 (I can't put 0 as it would give a math error), regardless of the width, the percent is 31.83% (114.6º). However, the common sense tells me that it should be 50% (180º). An easy way to understand it is by drawing a circle and then a square where one of the edges of the square passes over the center of the explosion. You will see that the square divides the circle into two parts, half of it extends over the square (hits the object) and the other part extends backward (miss).

## Question

Am I doing something wrong? 114.6º is quite different from 180º so my formula is wrong or my common sense is wrong. Any idea?

Comment: It would be really, really helpful to see a diagram of this. There are a lot of assumptions going on that are not clear from the text alone. In any case, I recommend to check that your calculator is set to radians instead of degrees :) Why do I say so? Because $\frac{1}{\pi}\approx 0.3183$, which is the number that you're giving in the text.

Comment: @MattiP. I will try to add a diagram. Regarding the math:
$TANH(\frac{wide/2}{distance})*2=2$. Then if radiants: $\frac{2}{2*\pi}$=0.3183. If degree: $2*\frac{180}{\pi}=114.6º$ and then $\frac{114.6}{360}=0.3183$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your equation is correct, you just have to be very careful with the units (degrees vs radians). If you're using radians, the formula for the percentage covered is
$$
\frac{\left(\arctan \frac{w}{2d}\right)}{\pi} \times 100\%
$$
As a numerical example, if we have $d=5$ and $w=10 \Rightarrow \frac{w}{2d}= 1$ and we get $\frac{\arctan 1}{\pi}=0.25$ or a quarter of the coverage. That should make perfect sense. On the other hand, if we let $d$ approach zero, we get
$$
\lim_{d \to \infty} \frac{\left(\arctan \frac{w}{2d}\right)}{\pi}  = \frac{\pi / 2}{\pi} = \frac{1}{2}
$$ which should make perfect sense again.

On the other hand, if we're using degrees, the formula is
$$
\frac{\left(\arctan \frac{w}{2d}\right)}{180^{\circ}} \times 100\%
$$
Also, try not to mix $\arctan$ with $\tanh$, those are two very different functions.

Comment: Oh, thank you!!! I have been using in excel TANH() thinking that it was the inverse of TAN, but I should have used ATAN(). Now with w=1 and d=0.1 it gives me 177º instead of 114º which makes much more sense.